# Could python split return None while the string has two continuous tab('\t')?

Tags: python, split

for example, if the string is: `"1\t2\t3\t\t4"`

Could it return the list like: `['1', '2', '3', None, '4']`

Comment: Are you asking if `split` will do this, or are you asking how to make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[x or None for x in "1\t2\t3\t\t4".split("\t")]
#>>> ['1', '2', '3', None, '4']
```

If you really wanted `int`s like in your example:

```
[int(x) if x else None for x in "1\t2\t3\t\t4".split("\t")]
#>>> [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```